# openpyxl format cell decimal precision

Tags: openpyxl, precision, number-formatting

I have a data frame that I exported to excel.  I'm looking for Python method to change the formatting for a column to maintain the float integrity of 6 decimal place precision.

ie..

11.123456 is being displayed as 11.12 in excel.

I know how to change the formatting in excel but am trying to include this in my python code.

I have imported the openpylx library and the BUILTIN_FORMATS does not have a preset.  I cannot find a way to manually build the format to 6 decimal places.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can use cell number_format attribute to set the cells number format per the Excel options in Right Click ---> 'Format Cells'---> 'Number' Tab. E.g. To change 11.123456 to be displayed in Excel with 6 decimal places use **ws[<cell>].number_format = '0.000000'**